# http concurrent requests to nodejs server giving same response to

Tags: node.js, http, concurrency, callback

while I am requesting two requests(with different login details) to nodejs server concurrently.
first request is waiting for callback. the same time the second request overriding the first request object in nodejs. once I got the response from call back its aplicable to both requests.

It's happens for all services in my nodejs server.

Comment: If your second request overrides the result of the first one, it seems that you store request result in some kind of shared memory - for example, in one `require`d object.

Comment: even also overrides the request object also after callback response

Answer (score 0):

Problem at my side. I did silly mistake

I was created the variables globally, that's why it's overwrite the objects.
Now I made the variable are local, then everything works fine.

Thanks